# Utopia or utopia

Tags: capitalization

Does one write Utopia (with capital) or utopia (without capital)?
Or does it not matter which one is chosen?

I do not know whether it matters, but I want to use it as follows:

> Using a (certain) view is still seen as a sort of ‘utopia’, as it is supposed to make (it) understandable with just a single glance.

(sentence is somewhat simplified)

Note: It is a utopia as this would be an unreachable goal.

I cannot seem to find a reliable (on-line) source. There does not seem a consensus.

Comment: Try looking it up in a dictionary and let us know what you found. *Utopia* with initial capital and without mean different things. See explanation and usage examples here:http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utopia Voting to close as GR.

Comment: I already checked m-w.com before asking the question, but I could not really make a distinction between the 1st and 2nd explanation. Unless Utopia is used when it is literally taking about the non-existing place and if it using in a non-literal way it should be used as utopia..?

Comment: If that has not clarified to you, let us know what really you are looking for.

Comment: I added an example use case on how I need/want to use the word utopia.

Comment: I wonder why *utopia* is set in quotes. There is no justification for that unless it is an actual quote. More to the point though, *utopia* is a place (and *Utopia* even more so). "Using a certain view" is not a place. It is not a country. The sentence should really read "using the view is still seen as *utopic*". In which case the question of capitalization does not even arise. Lastly, while we are at it, what does "using a view" even mean? I don't think *use* is a verb that makes sense here. In short: you've got more severe problems to take care of first.

Comment: I left some parts of the sentence out, the `(certain)` part is actually more descriptive. Same goes for `(it)`. About the quotes: I used them as I thought utopia was not literal/exact, which should have been indicated by the quotes. But I guess the example requires context to be helpful (which is why I did not include it from the start). It is not a sentence I use everyday and I do not know a more simple use of the word without losing the context...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on the context.

I'd use a capital letter if I describe a city/place as a utopia in lieu of it's name (perhaps as a callback to an earlier description), or if it was indeed the place name (within the lore of the story/setting).

> Utopia has vast green plains.

If I'm using it as part of a description, then I'd use a lowercase.

> The city had vast green plains, giving it an almost utopian feel.

Comment: So since I do not refer the the city itself directly, but more to its properties (being perfect), I should not need the capital letter?

Comment: @Veger exactly. It's a noun not a title, so lowercase U, unless you're using it in the way I suggested above, in which case, the capital is acceptable.